# is it possible to open an RFCOMM channel on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, rfcomm

is it possible to open an RFCOMM channel for bluetooth Connectivity between Mac OS and iOS for sending and receiving data.Any sample code available

Comment: No. It isn’t. Classic Bluetooth profiles are not available to iOS apps. You can use an L2CAP channel

Comment: @Paulw11 Any sample code available for reference.I am trying to send data between mac os and ios

Comment: I haven't tried this on macOS, but it should work https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo

Comment: is there any MacOS available for reference @Paulw11

Comment: CoreBluetooth is a cross platform framework and `openL2CAPChannel` is listed as being available on macOS 10.14+ so you should be able to use the Bluetooth code from my example on macOS.

Comment: openL2CAPChannel channel doesnt open for very long and closes.Any example to use it in the macOS

Comment: when opening on macos what should be the PSM value for openL2CAPChannelAsync @Paulw11

Comment: The PSM value is provided by the operating system In the `didPublishL2CAPChannel` peripheral delegate method. It is your responsibility to communicate this value to the central.  My sample does this using a characteristic on the peripheral.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 for help.I was able to use openL2CAPChannelAsync on macOS and open the channel, how to open on iOS as didDiscover method of CBCentralManager does not discover macOS to connect to it.i am trying to open on Mac and iOS simultaneously to pass data

Comment: This is how my sample works: One of your devices acts as a peripheral, the other as a central.  The peripheral advertises a service that the central discovers.  When the central connects to the peripheral it obtains the PSM from a characteristic on the peripheral.  Each device can then open the L2CAP channel.  This provides a bi-directional stream, so each side can now communicate via this stream

Comment: The ios app connects to the peripheral with a UUID established in didDiscover when the bluetooth scanning starts.This is how is open the channel on macOS         r = (selectedDevice?.openL2CAPChannelAsync(&l2cap, withPSM:BTChannels.Control, delegate: self))!
.However in the macOS app we open a l2cap channel and dont advertise and UUID for the iphone to connect to so we can do read/write over the channel.@Paulw11

Comment: Which device is your peripheral and which is your central?  Once you have a connection between your peripheral and your central, your peripheral publishes an L2CAP channel and advises the central of the PSM.  Once the central connects to the L2CAP channel using the PSM you have a bi-directional stream.  The central can use this to send data to & receive data from the peripheral and the peripheral can use it send data to & receive data from the central.  You should be able to easily port my sample code into a macOS class

Comment: To be honest, my example doesn't have the best structure.  I should re-factor to remove the bluetooth code from the view controller code.

Comment: @Paulw11The macOS is the central and iOS is the peripheral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204145/discussion-between-md12-and-paulw11).